# Understanding a lemma from Bauer's book

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

This lemma precedes the proof of the Radon-Nikodym Theorem in Bauer's book *Measure and Integration Theory*.

At the beginning of the proof he writes "we may obviously suppose that $\varrho(\Omega)\geq0$", but I can't find anywhere in the proof where this assumption is needed. Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am a bit bothered by the notation $\Omega_0 \cap \mathcal{A}$, since the two things are not the same type. I assume this is defined as follows?$$\{ B \subseteq \Omega : B= A \cap \Omega_0 \quad \mbox{for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$} \}?$$

Comment: @Michael Exactly this is the meaning.

Comment: I observe that the statement of the theorem is trivial if $\rho(\Omega)\leq 0$, since we can choose $\Omega_0$ as the empty set. So the only nontrivial case is $\rho(\Omega)>0$.  But I agree that I do not see where the assumption $\rho(\Omega)>0$ or $\rho(\Omega)\geq 0$ would be needed in the proof.

Comment: @Michael True! Am glad you confirmed my observation.

Comment: @Michael Other than that there doesn't seem to be any problem in proof ?

Comment: I didn't notice any problems.  I kind of skimmed over the last paragraph since the word "isotoneity" scares me (but I suppose that is defined by how it is used).  So if there were any hidden mistakes I would check for them in that last paragraph, but, I see no reason for there to be any mistakes.

Comment: @Michael Indeed "isotoneity" is rather scary word. Bauer use it to mean monotone.